# Azure B2C UserIsNew attribute is missing when logged in with external identity providers

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I use `UserIsNew` attribute for my Azure B2C user flow. Users log in with Angular app and I get this attribute/claim on the front-end. Also, I get an access token which is used as a bearer to access ASP.NET Core 3.1 web API.

And here's the problem - the access token works (contains the UserIsNew claim) when the user is Local (Email signup). But when it's an external user (Microsoft account in my case) I get the claim in the Angular app only. The access token does not have the custom attribute, thus web API returns access denied!

What am I missing?

## UPDATE

These are the claims I'm getting in the angular app:

[image: angular b2c claims]

And these are from server side (web API):

```
"claims": [
    {
        "issuer": "https://[mytenant].b2clogin.com/[guid]/v2.0/",
        "originalIssuer": "https://[mytenant].b2clogin.com/[guid]/v2.0/",
        "type": "exp",
    },
    {
        "issuer": "https://[mytenant].b2clogin.com/[guid]/v2.0/",
        "originalIssuer": "https://[mytenant].b2clogin.com/[guid]/v2.0/",
        "type": "nbf",
    },
    {
        "issuer": "https://[mytenant].b2clogin.com/[guid]/v2.0/",
        "originalIssuer": "https://[mytenant].b2clogin.com/[guid]/v2.0/",
        "type": "aud",
    },
    {
        "issuer": "https://[mytenant].b2clogin.com/[guid]/v2.0/",
        "originalIssuer": "https://[mytenant].b2clogin.com/[guid]/v2.0/",
        "properties": {
            "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/ShortTypeName": "idp"
        },
        "type": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider",
    },
    {
        "issuer": "https://[mytenant].b2clogin.com/[guid]/v2.0/",
        "originalIssuer": "https://[mytenant].b2clogin.com/[guid]/v2.0/",
        "type": "name",
    },
    {
        "issuer": "https://[mytenant].b2clogin.com/[guid]/v2.0/",
        "originalIssuer": "https://[mytenant].b2clogin.com/[guid]/v2.0/",
        "properties": {
            "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/ShortTypeName": "oid"
        },
        "type": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier",
    },
    {
        "issuer": "https://[mytenant].b2clogin.com/[guid]/v2.0/",
        "originalIssuer": "https://[mytenant].b2clogin.com/[guid]/v2.0/",
        "properties": {
            "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/ShortTypeName": "sub"
        },
        "type": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier",
    },
    {
        "issuer": "https://[mytenant].b2clogin.com/[guid]/v2.0/",
        "originalIssuer": "https://[mytenant].b2clogin.com/[guid]/v2.0/",
        "properties": {
            "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/ShortTypeName": "given_name"
        },
        "type": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname",
    },
    {
        "issuer": "https://[mytenant].b2clogin.com/[guid]/v2.0/",
        "originalIssuer": "https://[mytenant].b2clogin.com/[guid]/v2.0/",
        "properties": {
            "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/ShortTypeName": "family_name"
        },
        "type": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname",
    },
    {
        "issuer": "https://[mytenant].b2clogin.com/[guid]/v2.0/",
        "originalIssuer": "https://[mytenant].b2clogin.com/[guid]/v2.0/",
        "properties": {},
        "type": "emails",
    },
    {
        "issuer": "https://[mytenant].b2clogin.com/[guid]/v2.0/",
        "originalIssuer": "https://[mytenant].b2clogin.com/[guid]/v2.0/",
        "properties": {},
        "type": "tfp",
        "value": "B2C_1_susi",
    },
    {
        "issuer": "https://[mytenant].b2clogin.com/[guid]/v2.0/",
        "originalIssuer": "https://[mytenant].b2clogin.com/[guid]/v2.0/",
        "properties": {},
        "type": "nonce",
    },
    {
        "issuer": "https://[mytenant].b2clogin.com/[guid]/v2.0/",
        "originalIssuer": "https://[mytenant].b2clogin.com/[guid]/v2.0/",
        "properties": {
            "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/ShortTypeName": "scp"
        },
        "type": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/scope",
    },
    {
        "issuer": "https://[mytenant].b2clogin.com/[guid]/v2.0/",
        "originalIssuer": "https://[mytenant].b2clogin.com/[guid]/v2.0/",
        "properties": {},
        "type": "azp",
    },
    {
        "issuer": "https://[mytenant].b2clogin.com/[guid]/v2.0/",
        "originalIssuer": "https://[mytenant].b2clogin.com/[guid]/v2.0/",
        "properties": {},
        "type": "ver",
    },
    {
        "issuer": "https://[mytenant].b2clogin.com/[guid]/v2.0/",
        "originalIssuer": "https://[mytenant].b2clogin.com/[guid]/v2.0/",
        "properties": {},
        "type": "iat",
    }
],
```

**newUser** is missing.

## UPDATE 1

These are used flow User Attributes set up:

[image]

And this is App Claims set up:

[image]

Also, keep in mind - **I'm testing the scenario when the user signs up, so *UserIsNew* is expected every time.**

Comment: The language of question is not clear. If the token doesnt have claim - how do you get it in app? Could you please add sample decoded tokens? And tell what is expected and what is actual?

Comment: added client and server claims. `newUser` is missing

Comment: See your network traces, and see how many requests are going to service. newUser claim is a one time claim. If access token request is sent twice -> it wont have newUser claim. It worked for me bfor google bytheway

Comment: I know that. I delete user and register. But as I said, this only happens with external IdP's. No problem with local accounts.

Comment: You show id token in the app, but api receives access token not id token. So check access token in the app. Also I’m pretty sure we don’t output the newUser claim when executing the write technical profile for external accounts. You just need to add the claim there.

Comment: thank you! how can I add it there? I didn't get that part, sorry

Answer (score 1):

The reason why (Display Name, Email Address, Job Title, PhoneNumber, Postal Code) claims were not returned in the token was because the user was added as an external (guest) user. The user didn't go through the signup process and the value for these attributes were not collected. The attributes with no value are not returned in the token.

Once we signed-up with a new user account and provided values to these attributes, we were able to get the claims in the token. For existing users, if these attributes are not captured, you can use profile editing policy to populate values for these attributes.

In order to get these claims, you need to navigate to your User Flow and select below:

**User attributes:** Display Name, Email Address, Job Title, PhoneNumber(custom), Postal Code.

**Application claims:** Display Name, Email Address, Job Title, PhoneNumber(custom), Postal Code, Identity Provider Access Token, User is new, User's Object ID.

**Note:**

1. idp_access_token will only be returned if you signup/signin using a Social IDP.
2. newUser claim is returned at signup only.
3. In case of built-in policy, you can get either acr or tfp claim. Both these claims have policy name as value. To choose which claim should be returned in the token, you need to go to the properties blade of the user flow > Token compatibility settings > Claim representing user flow > use toggle button to either select tfp or acr.

Comment: I updated the question:
- I always test sign up scenario
- user DOES sign up with Azure AD, so values are collected during the process
- user flow has all the settings, see the update

The question was about _UserIsNew_ for external providers.